# Azure devops to reuse the artifacts already download in previous runs

Tags: build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, release

Currently we are using Nugget packages as our Azure artifacts and during the release process we download the artifact using "Download Package" task . It is working perfectly. But we noticed that even though we have downloaded the package already,during the next run of the pipeline in the same agent, again we have to download it. This is taking lot of time. So we want to prevent the package from getting download if it already present. Could you provide a way to reuse the already downloaded package.

Comment: Is this on a Self-Hosted agent or on Azure Agent? Also are those yamls or classic pipelines?

Comment: it is self-hosted agents and using classic pipeline

Comment: Can you package your artifacts and pull them in as packages instead of artifacts? .e.g.: nuget?

Comment: Yeah, we are using Nuget packages

Answer (score 2):

In release pipeline, the `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` (Example: `C:\agent\_work\r1\a`. Same as `Agent.ReleaseDirectory` and `System.ArtifactsDirectory`) is the directory to which artifacts are downloaded during deployment of a release. The directory is cleared before every deployment if it requires artifacts to be downloaded to the agent. This is a default behavior, we can not change it unfortunately.